# space as parameter to program from bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, whitespace

I'm running application from bash, like this

```
./app_name var1 var2 $var3
```

where `var3` is `--a b, --c d` and where `b` and `d` don't contain spaces.

Now I want to add parameter, `--e f`, to `$var3`, but `f` contains whitespace. The problem is that I'm trying to avoid changes in this line.

```
./app_name var1 var2 $var3
```

If I leave it like this, `app_name` understands two parts of `f` as two different arguments, and thus it fails to parse.

Can I change `var3` somehow so that it doesn't split `f` as two different args? I have tried putting quotes inside, escaping space but it didn't help.

Comment: META: Try to use `` for your code and parameters. This will make your questions easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that by making `var3` an array, for example:

```
var3=(--a b --c d --e "f1 f2")

./app_name var1 var2 "${var3[@]}"
```

This way `f1 f2` will be treated as a single argument.